# How to clear value in angular2-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have tried to implement angular2-datetimepicker control in my application. But it is showing todays date as default. But I need to have this with no default date selected.

This is the code piece

In HTML page

```
 <angular2-date-pickerformControlName="dateTimeElement" [settings]="{
bigBanner: true, format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a',defaultOpen: false,
timePicker: true,
closeOnSelect: true}"></angular2-date-picker>
```

Can someone tell how to avoid the default binding of this control?

Comment: It seems like this package does not support null values. You might want to use another package.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the documentation goes you can set NgModel to a date you want, which you can try setting null in the component.
See: https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-datetimepicker/issues/5

I suppose you can set NgModel as said in the readme:
[image]

See: https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-datetimepicker/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Even if we set the ngModel value to null, the date picker is setting the current date.

Comment: No. Actually assign some model property to ngModel and the value of model property is null. Like, in ts file `value = null` and in control, `(ngModel) = value`

Comment: I found a better control for my requirement [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime). This one is really good.